# Fundamental solution of a linear differential operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $L$ be a linear ordinary differential operator 
$$
L(D)=a_nD^n + a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+\dots + a_1 D + a_0.
$$
A fundamental solution is a distribution $E$ satisfying $L(D)E=\delta_0$. We want to show that $E$ is of the form
$$E=Hu,$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function and $u$ satisfies $L(D)u=0$.

The hint is to consider the expression 
$$
L(D)\varphi=\frac 1{2\pi}\int \frac{\hat\varphi(-x-ic)}{L(x+ic)}dx 
$$
from Malgrange-Ehrenpreis construction. I am not good at complex analysis so could anyone please guide me the way?

Comment: Just a remark, there must be a condition somewhere that $u$ is not identically zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be the solution of $L(D)u=0$ with 
$$
u(0)=u'(0)= … =u^{(n-2)}(0)=0, \quad u^{(n-1)}(0)=\frac1{a_n}.
$$
The multiple root at zero can also be expressed in the factorization  $u(x)=x^{n-1}v(x)$ with a smooth function $v$, $v(0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!\,a_n}$.

Then $Hu$ has the correct jump in the $(n-1)$th derivative at $x=0$ with all lower derivatives continuous and zero so that $L(D)(Hu)=δ_0$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for the answer. Still, I would like to know how to solve this using the 'hint' (although I like your method more). Do you happen to have an idea?